# Is there a time setting for UpSource to pull information from YouTrack

Tags: youtrack, upsource, jetbrains-hub

I have UpSource and YouTrack configured correctly and both can get information from one another. Yet I experienced something very odd. I pushed a commit to the master branch, UpSource displays the information correctly, yet I linked to an issue in the YouTrack issues and when I hover over this issue the information cannot be displayed and I cannot figure out why.

[image]

Now you'd think, something must be wrong with my configuration! But when I click on the link I redirect to the issue perfectly fine and then I see that the issue has been updated..?

[image]

Then, after a while I hover over it again and information is now correctly displayed within UpSource! My only logical explanation for this is that UpSource pulls information from YouTrack on a time base and not directly on hover. If this is the case, where can I find such a setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Upsource pulls issue details from YouTrack on demand. There is a timeout hardcoded during which this operation is completed (40 seconds). For some reasons an attempt to fetch issue data wasn't successful, more information about the reason might be found under /logs/upsource-frontend/warn.log or error.log